# Is there any way to keep data in form before executing submit

Tags: javascript

so I have this form

```html
<div class="container">
    <form class="form">
        <div class="rangeOfChanges">
            <label for="range">Range of changes</label>
            <input type="text" step="1" id="range" class="range" name="range" pattern="/(\d+-\d+|\d+)/g"/>
        </div>
        <div class="changeManyDevices">
            <div class="changeManyDevicesDesc">
                deviceType
            </div>
            <select name="device" id="device">
                <option value="a"></option>
                <option value="b"></option>
                <option value="c"></option>
                <option value="d"></option>
                <option value="e"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="changeManyWiresType">
            <div class="changeManyWiresTypeDesc">
                CableDim
            </div>
            <select name="cable" id="cable">
                <option value="1"></option>
                <option value="2"></option>
                <option value="3"></option>
                <option value="4"></option>
                <option value="5"></option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="changeManyWiresLength">
            <div class="changeWiresLengthDesc">
                CableLen
            <input type="text" id="anotherInput" />
        </div>
        <div class="updateManySegmentsData">
            <button type="submit" class="submitChanges">Submit</button>
          </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and now via javascript ( without using jQuery ) I would like to handle my form.
My goal is to detect which `input` and/or `select` field has changed, and based on `input.range` apply changes to my array. So I have to have `input.range` filled and check in which other field changes were made, and if any apply those changes to array when `submit` button is clicked. I have tried doing that, my solution only works to apply changes to all attributes, not only for those who were changed.

```js
function processData(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    const input = document.getElementById(`range`).value;
    const arrayOfInputRanges = input.replace(/\s/g, "").split(`,`);
    const regex = /(\d+-\d+|\d+)/g;
    const checkIfRegExp = regex.test(input);

    const deviceSelect = document.getElementById(`changeManyDevices`);
    const wireSelect = document.getElementById(`changeManyCables`);
    const wireInput = document.getElementById(`manyCablesInputChange`).value;
    const deviceSelectValue = deviceSelect.options[deviceSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    const wireSelectValue = wireSelect.options[wireSelect.selectedIndex].value;

    if (!checkIfRegExp) {
        alert(`wrong input`);
        return false;
    } else if (checkIfRegExp) {
        arrayOfInputRanges.forEach((element) => {
            if (element.indexOf(`-`) > -1) {
                //splitting array and sorting data.
                const splitRange = element.split(`-`).sort();
                for (let i = splitRange[0]; i <= splitRange[splitRange.length - 1]; i++) {
                    systemData.bus[i].deviceName = deviceSelectValue;
                    systemData.bus[i].cableType = wireSelectValue;
                    systemData.bus[i].cableLen_m = wireInput;
                }
            } else if (element.indexOf(`-`) === -1) {
                console.log(element);

            }
            // parseInt(element);
            // console.log(element);
        });
    }

    return false;
}

function submitChanges() {
    const submitFormButton = document.querySelector(`.changesForm`);

    submitFormButton.addEventListener('submit', processData);
}
```

I know that in my solution I just take whatever value is holded in both `select` elements, same with both `inputs`. Maybe the solution is to just clear `form` `inputs` and `selects` every time user submits form so he has to put those values once again, and if he does not provide those just keep whatever value is in array?

Comment: Simply store the previous values in variables, then on submit, just compare to those previous values, get the ones that were different, submit them, then keep track of those new values for next time.

Comment: but would it solve a case, where I have lets say 5 objects in systemData array, all of them with different data and all I want to do is change cableLen_m value ? In range `input` you can choose range of changes - meaning you can type eg. 4-9 and for those segments you can change one, two or three variables

Comment: You'd have to do the comparisons based on the shape of your data, but the approach itself doesn't change.